# Polynomial divibility over finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, galois-theory, divisibility, irreducible-polynomials

Let $p$ be a prime number, and let F := $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and let $f(t) \in F[t]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $d$. I have to show that $f(t)$ divides $t^{p^d}-t$. The hint in this practice exam is to consider the quotient ring $F[t]/f(t)$. Can someone give me an idea of how to start even thinking of this, or how I can imagine the quotient ring?

Comment: The reason to think about such a quotient (and what to look for in that quotient) is that $f$ divides $g$ iff $g\equiv 0$ in $F[x]/f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing your background, I'll refer only to basic properties of fields and field extensions. First, it follows immediately from the *definitions* that for any field $F$, if $f\in F[t]$ is irreducible of degree $d$,  the quotient $E=F[t]/(f)$ is a field extension of degree $d$. If $F=\mathbf Z/p$, then $E$ is a $\mathbf Z/p$-vector space of dimension $d$, hence is finite of cardinal $p^d$. Next, conclude by looking at the multiplicative group $E^*$ (hint: use Lagrange's theorem) .

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $F[t]/f(t)$ is a field of characteristic $p$ and of dimension $d$, as a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}/p$, so its elements verify $t^{p^d}-t=0$. Look your favorite reference on finite fields.  Deduce that the image of $t^{p^d}-t$ in $\mathbb{F}[t]/p(t)$ is zero.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not able to see the elements over the vector space. The elements of this space looks like $F_{d-1}t^{d-1} + F_{d-2}t^{d-2} + \dots + F_0$ So is the dimension of this vector space $p^d$, or each $F_i$ has all p possibilities? I'm not too sure how to deduce that in this vector space, $t^{p^d}$ = $t$.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field